# Combining multiple raster layers to make landcover map for Borneo

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, land-cover, arcgis-10.6, change-detection

I am currently making a landcover change map for a Kinabatangan, Sabah, Borneo for my undergrad dissertation. I downloaded landsat MSS and 8 images. These were pre-processed and both classified using unsupervised isodata classifications. Due to the restricted resolution I had to then use Google Earth Pro to delineate and map palm oil concessions (large palm oil sites) and smallholders (small farmers). I made polygons for each type and converted these to KML for GIS. These polygons were then changed to raster format so everything was the same. Both rasters were combined to make one palm oil layer. I standardised all the data e.g. all had the same projected coordinate system and cell size.

How do I combine my palm oil raster data with my 2014 landcover map (this was the only year the palm oil was seen)?

I essentially want three maps

1. 1973 Base landcover map, with these classes: Water; Forest and Non-forest
2. 2014 landcover map with combined palm oil data, with these classes: Water; Forest; Non-forest; Smallholders; Large Concessions
3. 1973 - 2014 Landcover change map, with these classes: Water; Forest; Non-forest; Smallholders; Large Concessions.

I have tried to use the raster calculator and also merge to new raster tools.

I have attached some pictures of what I am working on [1: Overview of map; 2: Overview of classes].

Comment: You images are not displaying, can you reupload?

Comment: I think you also need to rethink the classes in your final landcover change map. If it has the same classes as the 2014 LC map, how is it showing *change*? Maybe the final map could have classes along the lines of  'unchanged', 'deforested for palmoil', 'reforested', etc.  This could likely be accomplished w/ the raster calculator tool

Comment: Hey Nick thanks for your reply. The change I am wanting to show is from the 1973 map to the 2014 map. With the third map I'll change the class names to e.g. "Forest changed to large concessions etc". Regards to the raster calc how would I combine the "2014 land cover" raster with "Palm oil" raster? would it simply be an addition ("2014 land cover" + "Palm oil")?

Comment: For the raster calculator I would likely do something involving conditionals.

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm

Comment: It's hard to know what the exact expression will be without seeing the values. I would 1) ensure that the layers are in the same projection, resolution, snapped to the same grid, etc 2) look at the raster attribute table for both of your land cover layers to see what the underlying numerical values are for each class, ensuring that the values are consistent between the two for those classes they have in common

Comment: Then think about a way you could build an expression with conditionals that does something like "if 1973_layer == 2014_layer --> unchanged, else if 1973_layer == 'forest' and 2014_layer == 'concession', 'forest changed to concession', else if .... etc (using appropriate numerical values for each class instead of text). Doing this in one big raster calculator expression using conditional is probably possible but likely cumbersome. It may be easier to do it in pieces using some of the tools in SA>math>logical.

Comment: Hello Nick, I've just checked and both the palm oil layer and 2014 land cover layer are both in the same coordinate system etc. I standardised these to start. I have also looked at the attribute tables. The issue here lies that neither have common classes between them: 2014 landcover class: "Water", "Forest", "Other"; oil palm class: "Smallholders" and "Large concessions". Basically lots of areas that are forest in the 2014 landcover map are actually oil palm (either oil palm class) so hence pixels which are two things e.g. oil palm in the oil palm layer or forest in the landcover layer I want

Comment: to be represented by oil palm layer instead. So essentially when combined (2014 land cover and oil palm), areas which are forest stay as forest, areas which are oil palm change to oil palm? Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah yeah i misunderstood - So you are currently working on combining oil palm raster w/ 2014 landcover. Seeing screenshots of the attribute tables would help.

Comment: let's continue this in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106433/palm-oild

Comment: Hey Nick It won't let me chat there as I'm new. Is anywhere else appropriate? Being able to send images would be useful for us both.

Comment: hmm that's wierd.  you should be able top add images to origional post w/ edit

Comment: Yeah it is weird. I tried adding images again and it didn't work. Could we use whatsapp maybe ?

Comment: If you post contact info I'll contact you. Email better than whatsapp don't want to use phone

Comment: Sure! gy16cr@leeds.ac.uk - That's my uni email. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the set of following commands which I found useful - using gdal library:

Creating list of rasters that are in folder:

```
dir /s/b/a *.tif > list.txt
```

Creating an image mosaic:

```
gdal_merge --optfile list.txt -o output_raster.tif
```

Compression of raster:

```
gdal_translate -co "COMPRESS=LZW" input_raster.tif output_raster.tif
```

Compression of rasters in a batch:

```
for %i in (*.tif) do gdal_translate -co "COMPRESS=LZW" %i compress_%i
```